# django model reference, Add more contraint to reference

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, manytomanyfield

[image]I have a question about Django model references.

I want to add more constraints to a ForeignKey or ManytoManyField like this:

`question_id = models.ManyToManyField(Question(open==True))`

Or put another similar constraint:

Actually I don't want to show a question that is not open as a selection( heightened in Answer form like the image above), 
of course, I have done it by some query but does Django has any built-in support for it? I have tried some other way but it didn't work. Thanks!

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    """Give answers"""
    answer = models.TextField()
    question_id = models.ManyToManyField(Question(open==True))
    upVote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downVote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        """return string  """
        return self.answer
```

Comment: Can you show us the serializer?

Answer (score 1):

While you still can, change your model relations. What you have now is that an answer can be linked to multiple questions. However, answer contains up and down vote.

So I can create two questions:

1. Is 1 + 1 two?

   - yes
   - no
2. Is 1 + 1 three?

   - yes
   - no

I can link the answers "yes" and "no" to both questions, which can be convenient with a good interface and is normalized. **But** they will *share the up/down votes*. Instead, answer should have a foreign key to question, because an answer can only be linked to one question at a time, even if the answer text is identical to prevent sharing of the up and down votes.

Secondly, we generally don't name fields `question_id`, but `question`:
From an object relation perspective, you relate an answer to a question not to a question id. (Under the hood, `question_id` is created to allow faster lookups and to serve as field name in the underlying database table).

On to your actual problem: you want to limit the available choices, which is what [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) does for you. So you would end up with this:

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    """Give answers"""
    answer = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers',
        limit_choices_to={'open': True},
    )
    upVote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downVote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        """return string  """
        return self.answer

# Serializer
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('answer', 'upVote', 'downVote', 'question_id')
```

As you can see, your serializer can reference the magic field `question_id`.